# Test return value of a spy

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am developing an Ionic app. The `calling` function lets the user call the number in `factory.call`.

```js
factory.call = '345-678-9087';

factory.calling = function(){
    return $window.location.href = 'tel:' + factory.call;
};
```

This is the Jasmine test for the above,

```js
it('calling method', function(){
    spyOn(factory, 'calling');
    factory.calling();
    expect(typeof(windowMock.location.href)).toEqual('string');
});
```

The above test passes just fine, but it does not test the exact value that `factory.calling()` returns. I have tried the following with no luck.

1)

```js
it('calling method', function(){
    var emergency = spyOn(factory, 'calling');
    factory.calling();
    expect(emergency).toEqual("'tel:' + factory.call");
});
```

2) `spyOn(factory, "calling").andCallThrough().`

3) `spyOn(factory, "calling").andReturn("'tel:' + factory.call").`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, your factory is not returning anything:

```
factory.calling = function(){
    return $window.location.href = 'tel:' + factory.call;
};
```

Calls to $window.location.href that are an assignment will not return anything. Seems to me that that call should not be there and your method should be:

```
factory.calling = function(){
    return 'tel:' + factory.call;
};
```

Doing it this way, you have a return value. Also, you are not storing the value that is returned anywhere that you can test it. In general, you use a spy to check to see if the method was called, like this:

```
it('calling method', function(){
    spyOn(factory, 'calling');
    factory.calling();
    expect(factory.calling).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

To check what the method returns, you can call it within the `expect` block like this:

```
it('calling method', function(){
    expect(factory.calling()).toEqual('tel: ' + factory.call);
});
```

Or you can call it via an anonymous function like this:

```
it('calling method', function(){
    expect(function(){return factory.calling();}).toEqual('tel: ' + factory.call);
});
```

Or you can call it first and then check the value it returns like this:

```
it('calling method', function(){
    var result = factory.calling();
    expect(result).toEqual('tel: ' + factory.call);
});
```

I might also suggest that you test with fixed data that you provide since a test of this type should not be hitting a database. Also, you should always stick to OAPT (like you have done.)

Comment: When I check the return value of the function `factory.calling`, it gives me an error - `Expected undefined to equal 'tel: 345-678-9087'.`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at your factory close enough. You should look at it. It doesn't return anything. You are calling a method that does not return anything ($window.location.href) and returning that return value (therefore, `undefined`). Seems like that call to $window.location.href should not be there, but I'm not familiar with the app.

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested, it gives me the same error - `Expected undefined to equal 'tel: 345-678-9087'.`

Comment: Update your code in the question, please, so that we can see the changes.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure you still need this, but call info contains "returnValue" property.
So it can be tested like this:
expect($scope.isFilterError.calls.first().returnValue).toBeFalsy();